# read specific lines from a text file in matlab and associating the lines together

Tags: matlab, fgets

I have a text file that have many sets of 11 lines.

For each set, I would like to read line 2 and line 11 out of the 11 lines. 
and associate the 2 lines together. how do I get about doing it?

I used "fgets" but I dunno how to read just specific lines. Help much needed. thanks!

```
 fid = fopen('images_list1.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);
char line[2];

while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to keep getting lines of text from the file, keeping only every 2nd and 11th line:

```
% open the file
fid = fopen('images_list1.txt');

% initialize a counter
count = 0;

% keep reading the file
while 1;

    % get a line of text
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    count = count + 1;

    % exit if the line is empty
    if tline == -1;
        break;
    end

    % check modulus of count for every 2nd and 11th line
    if mod(count,11) == 1;
        tline_2nd = tline;
    elseif mod(count,11) == 10;
        tline_11th = tline;
        % do something with the 2nd and 11th lines ("associate" them)
    end


end
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help. it is working after i place "count= count +1; after tline = fgetl(fid);